# How to set propagation direction of a source in Meep?

Tags: direction, meep

I have quite a simple question: how can I set the direction of a continuous source in Meep?

To be more specific, for example, let's say I want a continuous source to interact with a Bragg grating at a 30 deg angle (2D). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps more useful to think about what kind of source will generate a planewave incident at 30 degrees (which seems to be what you're interested in).  If z is your direction of propagation, an infinite sheet of dipoles in the xy plane will do this.

Check out the user interface page [here](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Scheme_User_Interface/#source).  For a 3D geometry I'd specify a source with 2D size (or a 1D line of dipoles if your simulation is in 2D), then create your structure rotated by the desired angle (rotate by specifying the block's e1, e2, e3 axis).